# what is role of a colon in Purebasic. What steps does this code will take?

Tags: reference, basic

hi I'm a beginner of purebasic and I'm trying to execute and analyze some code and I dont understand what are these

```
' : '??



*palmTemp.CvPoint : *temp.CvPoint : *additional.CvPoint
 *storage.CvMemStorage = cvCreateMemStorage(0) : cvClearMemStorage(*storage)
```

I'll appreciate if you can tell me the what this code actually implement!!

Answer (score 0):

Just concatenation of commands, ref. 
[On-line manual](https://www.purebasic.com/documentation/reference/general_rules.html)